# How would i fetch every single user my client has cached (DISCORD.JS V12)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Basically I am wondering (for example) if i were to want to send a message to every user my bot has cached like how I can do `client.users.cache.get(id).send("Message")`
but for every user.

Answer (score 0):

You would use:

```js
client.users.cache.each(user => user.send('message')):
```

**However**, this is against Discord's terms of service, and your bot will be at risk of being banned. I highly suggest avoiding this feature in your bot.